# Php Mysql Loop Method

Tags: php, mysql, loops, methods

I have a method for the images, but the addition comes on the same image, and I have 16 images, and I want a Loop to add the images from h_ID = 1 to h_ID = 16, and I do not know how

```
<?php
$x = 1;
while ($x <= 16){
    $x++;
    $getImages = $db->query("select * from table1 where h_ID = {$x} ")->getRow();
    $x++;
}
?>
```

Comment: there is no point to have two `$x++;` in the loop

Comment: What do you want to do with the result? Right now, you're only assigning to a variable and doing nothing with it.

Comment: can't you just select based on `BETWEEN` id 1 and id 16, then fetch the results

Comment: did not work , Only one variable is called, I want 16 variables in the same line

Comment: If you want to preserve all 16 values to process them at a later time, after the loop - then add them to an _array_, instead of overwriting $getImages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put all the data into an array ( e.g.  `$getImages[]` ) thru the while loop, and then use a foreach loop to do what you want (e.g. display the images one by one)

Note: there is no point to use two $x++; in your loop, otherwise you will skip half of the records from the 16 total records

So the code :

```
<?php
$x = 1;

while ($x <= 16){
    $getImages[] = $db->query("select * from table1 where h_ID = {$x} ")->getRow();
    $x++;
}

// when display / using the image , use a foreach loop

foreach($getImages as $Images){

//do something like echo <img src='$Images'> or whatever you want to accomplish

}
?>
```